# Multilingual App Toolkit for web applications

Tags: localization, windows-8, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, multilingual

I have come across this very interesting tool for Visual Studio 2012 development of windows apps called Multilingual App Toolkit - further information [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/10/03/multilingual-app-toolkit-for-developing-windows-store-apps-using-visual-studio-2012.aspx)

This is very clever how it generates resources based on selected languages etc.

Being a web application developer who develops multi lingual applications, I would love something similar, with same functionality available. For example, I am currently developing an MVC4 application for a client who has a requirement to support multiple languages. Is such a tool available to assist me with this? Or is there away to use the Multilingual App Toolkit for such web sites? Any other similar tools available?

Answer (score 4):

The Multilingual App Toolkit v3.0 now supports ASP.NET MVC projects.  See the blog announcement: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/matdev/archive/2014/04/14/announcing-multilingual-app-toolkit-v3-0.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to do what the Visual Studio extension would otherwise do for you in a Windows Phone / Windows Store project. The extension puts some MSBuild imports in your project file and sets-up your existing resource files so the are generated by the use of the XLIFF files.

For details, please see: http://damsteen.nl/blog/using-the-microsoft-multilingual-app-toolkit-with-asp.net-mvc-or-any-other-.net-project-type

Comment: really nice but doesn't actually work for me. I get the error: "Could not copy the file "obj\Debug\de\PROJECTNAME.resources.dll" because it was not found"